# Get innerText of td returns error Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value 0.51 from the table below:

HTML:

```
<div id=myDiv">    
<table class="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Text1:</td>
                <td class="data"><strong>0.51</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text2:</td>
                <td class="data"><strong>2199</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var foo= document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByClassName("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
var other=foo.innerText
```

However, the following piece of code:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByClassName("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
```

is returning the error:

```
TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because (with apologies) `NodeList` objects don't have a method called `getElementsByTagName`.

Let's break it down:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv")
```

Finds the *single element* with the `id` `"myDiv"`.

```
.getElementsByClassName("myTable")
```

Finds *a list* of elements within it that have the class `"myTable"`.

```
.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
```

...fails because the *list* doesn't have a method called `getElementsByTagName`.

Individual items within the list from `getElementsByClassName` have the method, but not the list.

So for instance, this would use the *first* element with the class `"myTable"`:

```
var foo= document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
// Change here ------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

But you're better off with the newer (but better-supported) `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. In this case:

```
var foo = document.querySelector("#myDiv .myTable td");
```

...would give you the first `td` in the first `.myTable` inside the `#myDiv`, and

```
var foo = document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv .myTable td");
```

...would give you a list of *all* of the `td` elements in *all* of the `.myTable` elements in `#myDiv`.

`querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` are supported in IE8, whereas `getElementsByClassName` is not.

Comment: Not your fault there's no `NodeList.prototype.getElementsByTagName`, I'm sure ;)

Comment: aha, got it. Apologies accepted. If the index of the array is specified the method is there.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: The DOM, in general, isn't my fault (thankfully!). I've made some boneheaded design decisions in my time, but... *(Edit: Oh, I see what you did there. :-) )*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, lol... But seriously, I think design decisions like that make more sense if you think about it from an implementation perspective. The DOM is meant to be implementable in arbitrary languages and environments, so I think they just wanted to spec enough to get things done without adding a lot of sugar. If implementors had to do too much fiddling around it might not be adopted as widely, and there can always be abstractions.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: Yeah, but `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)`?! ;-)

Comment: Heh, that's a great example. I still think it falls into the same bucket, though. "Let's see, nodes are like collections, so we need to be able to add and remove things. `node.appendChild` and `node.removeChild`? Yeah, that works, nice and symmetrical." If you only think about it from an implementation perspective and don't worry about usage, it doesn't seem that weird. From that angle, it seems more weird to tell a member of a collection to remove itself than it does to tell a collection to remove one of its members.

Answer (score 2):

You could use instead:

```
document.querySelector('#myDiv .myTable td'); 
// cleaner code, since you are looking for 1 element
```

Anyway, your problem is that `.getElementsByClassName("myTable")` gives you a list, and you would need a for loop to go thru that. 
You could use `.getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0]` that would get you a single element. And then use:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sure! Was actually reading your answer and wondering if I add something useful... (+1 btw)